# Where can I post a question about a problem with mobile phone?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about a problem with Samsung J7 mobile phone?

Answer (score 12):

[**Android** Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the right place for you, as Samsung J7 is an **Android** phone.

[I am an experienced user](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/205764) on Android Enthusiasts, and before you post your question, please make sure

- It's not about developing or debugging an application. You should instead navigate to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
- You're not asking for software/application recommendation. We are there to solve problems or provide help and hints there. If you're very sure that you want an app as a solution, please navigate to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- You're not asking for shopping recommendation, or looking for marketing data or statistics. We want to help problems with your phone, not your business.

And please notice that:

- We can provide different solutions or partial help to extreme or weird cases, like [controlling Android phone with broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42105). However, we can't fix your broken screen or repair a faulty camera. The aftersale stations and repair shops in your local area may be able to provide better help in these cases.
- [Stack Exchange is not a series of sites for seeking urgent or timely helps.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/) Android Enthusiasts may not provide any answers/tips/hints in a few hours. If your problem is too rare, you can get a small [Tumbleweed badge](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38) :)

We already have a bunch of nice questions on various issues (with good answers!). You can [search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search) for existing posts about your problem. If none of them solves your problems, feel free to [ask a new one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

Samsung J7 is an Android mobile.

If your problem is related to software, ask it on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com).

If that is a hardware problem (like screen crashed/ USB port damaged), there is no site for you to ask.

Since you said that you have a problem with Samsung J7, I hope it is not related to programming or any third party applications.

Read their [How to Ask](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section before asking it on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: Android.SE covers hardware issues too, for example [broken-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen) is a tag with 200+ questions, many recent, and they are not being closed as off-topic.

Comment: I have the links directing to What's-on-topic? in my answer. The How-to-Ask page is almost the same across all SE sites.