# Where to ask "How to reinforce USB-C cable for Android phone"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would I ask the following question? I found a [similar type of question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299240/where-can-i-post-a-question-about-a-problem-with-mobile-phone/299242#299242) here on Meta, but my question is specific to reinforcing USB[-C] cables used for charging a phone.

> My wife's Moto X4  is repeatedly knocked off her nightstand/bed by our
>   cat, and have gone through several cables where the metal connector on
>   the USB-C side of the cable gets bent at about a 45 Degree angle, the
>   internal connections get broken, and the cable no longer works.  Are
>   there any recommendations on how to prevent this from happening?  Some
>   product to reinforce the end of the cable (to prevent it from flexing
>   on the end of the cord?), ways to store the device to prevent the cat
>   from knocking it down, or different cable designs that may reduce the
>   angular stress applied to the port?

Comment: This seems to be pretty broad; you're asking for a shopping rec, techniques to prevent the phone from falling, and another shopping rec for different criteria.  I don't think that's on-topic anywhere.

Comment: I guess without a specific place in mind to ask the question, I had a bit of trouble narrowing down the scope... ultimately the question is 'how can I maximize the life of the phone and minimize my total cost over the lifetime of the device while factoring in malicious cats'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ways to store the device to prevent the cat from knocking it down,

That specific part sounds like it could be solved with a [Lifehack](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/). I bet that there's somebody over there who has a good idea. Their [Help Center](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states:

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Lifehacks is a place to ask about seemingly intractable, stubborn problems that need a bit of thinking **"outside the box"**. If your question is…
>
> - seeking uncommon solutions to common physical problems;
> - asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to achieve a certain task or solve a specific problem;
> - looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an obvious solution

Comment: Looks like I found a similar question over in lifehacks, but specific to micro-usb - https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/how-can-i-fortify-micro-usb-connectors